# How to find $∂^2z/∂x^2$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If we have $∂z/∂x=∂z/∂u+∂z/∂v$, what is the technique to find $∂^2z/∂x^2$? It seems like you just kind of square both sides but that seems like an informal way to think about it..

Comment: Is it not simply a case of differentiating the RHS WRT $x$ again?

Comment: That's what I thought at first but nope, doesn't seem like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**: use the binomial theorem, $(D_u + D_v)^2 = D_u^2 + 2 D_u D_v + D_v^2$. I'm sure you can identify what $D_{u_i}$ stands for.

Cheers!

Comment: You're missing a factor 2 :)

Comment: Of course! Thanks a lot @Noiralef for the correction.

Comment: @Dmoreno What does $D_{u_i}$ stand for?